What do the numbers or tags on the Apache Cassandra FAQ page mean?
I'm new Apache Cassandra and I was just going through the FAQ page of Apache Cassandra. I see sentences such as follows in the answers:

See 256 and 43 for more gory details.


See topology-changes.

I am not able to figure out what does the 256 and 43 or topology-changes mean here. They are in pink color but there is no hyperlink behind them taking anywhere. Also can't find anything on the FAQ page. Tried to search with these keywords in the search field on the Cassandra website but didn't get any meaningful results.
Can someone please help me understand this? If this is not a right place for this question then please don't downvote it, just let me know in comment and I can move it to the right forum/section. I reached here from the Community-> Discussions page

For the first entry you cited, they are referring to tickets where the issue is discussed specifically CASSANDRA-256 and CASSANDRA-43.
The second one should be a link to the Topology changes page on the website.
I've logged CASSANDRA-19586 to get the page fixed. Thanks for bringing it to our attention. Cheers! 
